# Design for fetching liked resources

Tags: object-oriented, architecture, web-development, domain-driven-design

I have three resources `Hotel`, `Address` and `Image`. A hotel can have may images but only one address. While showing hotel details I need to fetch its address as well as all images of it so, in my controller the following code goes:

```
function getHotel(req, res) {
  const { hotelId, merchantId } = req.params;
  Hotel.search(req, [['id', '=', hotelId], ['merchant_id', '=', merchantId]])
      .then(function then_(hotel) {
        Hotel.searchAddress(req, hotelId).then(function then_(address) {
          hotel.address = address;
          Hotel.searchImages(req, hotelId).then(function (images) {
            hotel.images = images;
            res.status(200).json({ hotel });
          });
        });
      }).catch(function catch_(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send();
      });
}
```

It can be seen that the `SQL` queries are inside the static class methods but the more painful concern is that the code seems procedural to me. I know there is a `Repository` pattern but I haven't used it much yet. How can I make the given code more OOP and flexible?

Comment: I'd consider moving the `Hotel.searchAddress` and `Hotel.searchImages` calls out to the scope of `getHotel`, and have them write to a local. Then all the promises can be passed to `Promise.all()`, which assembles the response. At the moment, you just have a linear sequence of steps, wrapped up in an arrowhead

Comment: @Caleth: sounds fine, why not make an answer from your comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider moving the `Hotel.searchAddress` and `Hotel.searchImages` calls to the same level. Then all the promises can be passed to [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which assembles the response.

This is possible because none of your steps depends on data from the outer promises. Where there is a data dependancy, you can nest only the dependant calls as in your example, which will minimise the depth of callbacks.

e.g.

```
function getHotel(req, res) {
  const { hotelId, merchantId } = req.params;
  Promise.all([
      Hotel.search(req, [['id', '=', hotelId], ['merchant_id', '=', merchantId]]), 
      Hotel.searchAddress(req, hotelId),
      Hotel.searchImages(req, hotelId)
    ]).then(function (values) {
        const { hotel, address, images } = values; 
        hotel.address = address;
        hotel.images = images;
        res.status(200).json({ hotel });
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send();
    });
}
```

Comment: There may be the case that the hotelId is invalid. I think fist we need to fetch hotel and then address and images in parallel.

Comment: If hotelId is invalid, then *at least one* of the promises will return an error, and the error status will be returned. We can then ignore the other two values. The point is *not* to minimise how much we search for, but to minimise how long we have to wait for our searching to finish

Comment: Yes, but the issue if `Hotel.search` returns `null` i.e. no record found then also other two searches will be performed which is not wanted. wdyt?

Comment: So? Deciding not to do the other searches probably slows the whole operation down more than just doing it, especially as you expect there to be a result

Comment: Is `Promise.all` runs in parallel? if not how its fast?

Comment: from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) : "The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved [...]. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects."

Comment: It means it still runs the searches in sequence, not parallel right?

Comment: Promises run asynchronously. That's not required to be parallel, but it is likely to be, for things like database accesses.